# Flickering mousenter mouseleave with delay, button list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a list(`<p>`) with buttons. When I move my mouse over them it's a 1,2 sec delay before my textbox are marked with yellow to show where I can write. When I move my mouse away they turn normal(white).

My problem is when I quickly hover my mouse over the buttons back and forth a lot of the textboxes gets marked.
I had hoped the 1,2 sec delay would have worked then but it doesn't. But it works if I move my mouse slowly in and out of the button.

Here is a fiddle to it:  http://jsfiddle.net/Pota/Fj6E6/

Here is my JavaScript code

```
$(function () {
    $("p.pRespRoleId").mouseenter(function () {
        var timeOut = 1200;
        $this = $(this);
        $this.data("delay", setTimeout(function () {
            mouseInRespRoleId();
        }, timeOut)
             );
    })


.mouseleave(function () {
       $this = $(this);
       if ($this.next(mouseOutRespRoleId()).is(":visible")) {
           clearTimeout($this.data("delay"));
           mouseOutRespRoleId();
       }
       else {
           $this.next("p.pRespRoleId").show();
       }
   });

});
```

and

```
function mouseInRespRole() 
            {
            var txtInRespRole = document.getElementById("<%=txtRespRoleName.ClientID %>");
                txtInRespRole.style.background = "#FFFF00";
                if (document.getElementById('txtRespRoleName').value == '') 
                {
                    document.getElementById('txtRespRoleName').innerHTML = txtInRespRole;
                    return false;
                }
            }


            function mouseOutRespRole() 
            {
            var txtOutRespRole = document.getElementById("<%=txtRespRoleName.ClientID %>");
                txtOutRespRole.style.background = "white";
                if (document.getElementById('txtRespRoleName').value == '') 
                {
                    document.getElementById('txtRespRoleName').innerHTML = txtOutRespRole;
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: With this amount of code, it's definitely worth making a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with your HTML and JS code? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks for re-enforcing that......

Comment: Hello guys!

Ive made a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pota/Fj6E6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsFiddle is surely confusing to me (I am not sure what you are trying to achieve - there is a tangible possibility that you are overcomplicating things). I hope I got your requirement right...

Anyway, I believe your logic was right, but there were some flaws in the implementation. So, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/YTFYX/) is a modified (and partially corrected) version of your jsFiddle, which does what (I believe) you were trying to achieve.

Your use of *'$this.next(mouseOutRespRoleId()).is(":visible")'* was sure the most confusing, so I removed it completely. (In case it was fulfilling some other, not obvious purpose, you'll have to provide a more detailed description.)

The main problem was that `$this.next(mouseOutRespRoleId()).is(":visible")` was never evaluating to true, thus never clearing the timer that called `mouseInRespRoleId()`.

**EDIT**:
I updated my [jsFiddle illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/YTFYX/) so that it takes care of IE9's strange behaviour (a.k.a. bug (?)). It should work without flickering now.
Short explanation of the problem:
Aparantly, in IE9 the mouse-events generation has some "timing issues", so that when entering (mouseOver) and leaving (mouseOut) a component multiple times rapidly, sometimes the mouse-events order gets messed up. E.g.:
The following event sequence (i.e. actual events):

```
mouseOver -> mouseOut -> mouseOver
```

May produce the following (obviously wrong) javascript-event sequence (i.e. events triggered by JS-engine in IE9):

```
mouseOver -> mouseOver(!) -> mouseOut(!)
```

So, I added an extra `clearTimeout($this.data("delay"))` in the "mouseentered" handler-function, in order to clear any pending scheduled executions of "mouseInRespRoleId".
It does not work perfectly on IE9 (and probably previous versions of IE - not tested), but it is as good as it can get (afaik).

(NOTE: It still works as intended on other (non-buggy) browsers.)

Comment: Hey Expert. I tried you new version of jsFiddel, but still. If you drag ure mouse quickly back and forth to the button you will see that the textbox is flickering in yellow. It shouldent. It shall only be yellow when you hover the mousebutton over the button for 1.2sec when there is no text. What can be done to achieve this?

Comment: I tried it in Chrome and Firefox and it works as expected. Please, note that because of '<p class="pRespRoleId">' the mouse-events are bound to the containing <p> element, not the button itself (I changed the background to blue for clarity). If you want the event bound to the button, move 'class="pRespRoleId"' in the button tag.

Comment: Hey again Expert.

Yeah, I tested it on Firefox and it worked as intended. But here is a strange thing. I changed the $("li.liRespRole") With $("#Button6")
And guess what, then it started to flicker in Firefox too :)

But i need to use InternetExplorer. So what could be done then to make it work without flickering. As i said i tried to use ButtonID instead, but that dident do the trick.

Strange stuff :S

Comment: It works in IE10 and Firefox, but not in IE9. What could be wrong?

Comment: What could be wrong ? IE9 !!! (Sorry, I don't have a IE9 available. Alaways use latest versions of browsers, please ! It is good for the internet. It is good for us all...)

Comment: Well the thing is that i need to use IE9. Do someone have any idea of what could be done?

Comment: @Pota I managed to get my hands on a IE9 installation. I updated my answer to address IE9's strange (= buggy) behaviour.